# Remove row with spesific value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
value1       value2
aa7bbc       aaaa
ss           ss0
qqq          wwww
nn77         qqee
```

I want to remove the row that :

- has digit in value
- begin with `nn`
- has less than two characters

I've tried this:

```
df[~df.value1.str.contains(r'\d')]
```

but that doesn't cover everything I need. what is the most efficient way to solve this?

Thank you so much

Comment: What does that mean - `has fewer than two characters`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to refine your regex with OR to match any of the conditions.

`r'(\d)|(^nn)|(^.?$)'`

this is:

`\d` for a contained digit

OR

`^nn` for begin with nn

OR

`^.?$` for 0-1 chars (less than two characters).

try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
value1       value2
aa7bbc       aaaa
ss           ss0
qqq          wwww
nn77         qqee"""), sep=r"\s+")

df = df[~df.value1.str.contains(r'(\d)|(^nn)|(^.?$)')]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  value1 value2
1     ss    ss0
2    qqq   wwww
```

Answer (score 1):

Use operators to filter based on the conditions

```
    df[ (~df.value1.str.contains(r'\d')) & (df.value1.str.len() < 2) & (df.value1.str.startswith('nn') ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def has_digit(str):
     return any(char.isdigit() for char in str)

new_df=df[len(df['value1'])>=2 and not df['value1'].startswith("nn") and not has_digit(df['value1'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it :

```
mask_no_digit =( ~df.value1.str.contains(r'\d')) & (~df.value2.str.contains(r'\d'))
mask_no_nn = (~df['value1'].str.startswith('nn')) & (~df['value2'].str.startswith('nn'))
mask_no_2_characters = (~df['value1'].str.len()<=2 ) & (~df['value2'].str.len()<=2)

df[mask_no_digit & mask_no_nn & mask_no_2_characters]
```

---

Output :

```
  value1 value2
2    qqq   wwww
```